# Mysterious margins on webpage

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a Wordpress theme and noticed that the whole body of the page is pushed down a bit. I used the inspector in Chrome to find the problem and I found the following styles:

```css
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
```

If I delete this in the inspector the body of the page snaps back to the top. But here is the weird thing. I tried deleting my whole stylesheet to see if the problem was in the css, but the problem is still there. So my guess id that Chrome must be adding these lines, but why? It works fine in IE and Edge.

*Edit: I tried clearing css cache in Crome, but no difference..*
*Edit: I tried adding css reset to the stylesheet but still no difference...*

CSS (quite messy, but work in progress): https://codeshare.io/sr0sg

[image]

Comment: Try adding: `* { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important }` to see what happens. If the padding/margin goes away, one of your elements is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Tried it. It does mess up the entire webpage completely but it does still not remove the mysterious code.

Comment: What if you add this piece of code in your HTML code, in the header? Maybe the mysterious magic happens in another CSS file?

Comment: Also does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: As I wrote I have already checked IE and Edge. I tried adding your zero margins to the head of my index.php but no difference still.

Comment: i dont think chrome would add this...it will complete broken tags, etc but not new stylerules! disable plugins, its something in your code id say. A handy way to know is to view source and compare it to your rendered output in inspector - ie if the code is in view source, it is not chrome adding it. It might be conditional to chrome etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to your `functions.php` file:

`add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');`

The CSS you have highligted above is added by WP to make space for the WordPress admin bar. You can also hide the admin bar by going to Users > Your profile > "Show tool bar when editing site" in the admin area.

Comment: Thanks! That solved it! I have had problems with the admin bar covering up content ever since I started making floating divs. Although this is an aggressive method it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little bit old, but the suggested solution is too much drastic. I suggest to maintain the admin bar and just remove the weird CSS.

This can be accomplished with this snippet:

```
add_action('get_header', 'remove_admin_bar_weird_css');
function remove_admin_bar_weird_css() {
    remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb');
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm and admin bar is still available.
Should be an accepted answer IMO